# TinyMCE 5: Autocomplete that can be ignored so you can just type your own entry

Tags: tinymce

I want to help the user author handlebars/mustache templates so when they type a `{` character, an autocomplete of known template values comes up to assist the user.  But the user may not want to choose one of the suggested options, they might just want to continue typing a new template value and terminate it with a `}`.  In the example in the code below, the options `"Order Number"` and `"Delivery Date"` are the known autocomplete options, but I want the user to be able to type `{Invoice Number}` for example.

I've succeeded in make this work in one way.  As a user is typing `{Invoice Number}` I add it to the list of allowed options in the autocompleter `fetch` function.  So the user can get what they want into the document *if* the click on the suggested option.  Clicking fires the `onAction` function.  I want `onAction` to fire as soon as the user types the closing handlebars character i.e. `}`.

Here is the code I have tried.  I am using TinyMCE 5.

````
    let template = (function () {
        'use strict';

        tinymce.PluginManager.add("template", function (editor, url) {
            const properties = [
                {value: "Order Number", text: "Order Number"},
                {value: "Delivery Date", text: "Delivery Date"}
            ];

            const insertNewProperty = function(value) {
                let property = {value: value, text: value};
                properties.push(property);
                return property;
            };

            editor.ui.registry.addAutocompleter('autocompleter-template', {
                ch: '{',
                minChars: 0,
                columns: 1,
                fetch: function (pattern) {
                    return new tinymce.util.Promise(function (resolve) {
                        let filteredProperties = pattern ? properties.filter(p => p.text.indexOf(pattern) > -1) : properties;
                        if (filteredProperties.length > 0) {
                            resolve(filteredProperties);
                        } else {
                            resolve([{value: pattern, text: pattern}]);
                        }
                    });
                },
                onAction: function (autocompleteApi, rng, value) {
                    let property = properties.find(p => p.value === value);
                    if (!property) {
                        property = insertNewProperty(value)
                    }
                    let content = `{${property.text}}`;

                    editor.selection.setRng(rng);
                    editor.insertContent(content);

                    autocompleteApi.hide();
                }
            });

            return {
                getMetadata: function () {
                    return {
                        name: "Learning",
                        url: "https://stackoverflow.com"
                    };
                }
            };
        });
    }());
})();```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add a matches function to your callbacks, along with your onAction, this help you do it.

```
matches: function (rng, text, pattern) {
        if(pattern.endsWith('}')){
            pattern = pattern.replace('}', '');

            /**
             * Check if pattern does not match an existing 
             * variable and do what you want
             */
            return true;
        }
    },
```

And make sure the function always returns true.